# Spartacus- Multi Dimensional Product

Tags: spartacus-storefront

does spartacus support multi dimensional structure  for variants flow , we created 3 variant category and assigned to product . It could display product properly in normal storefront but on spartacus page not find.

Answer (score 1):

Spartacus doesn't support Multi-D variants yet, it's planned for Q1 2021, see roadmap:
https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/spartacus-roadmap/#features-planned-for-the-rest-of-q4-2020-and-into-q1-2021